# Flask site can't get static files after deploy

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I developed a website using flask and in my computer everthing runs ok using localhost. But when i deploy the code it returns 404 to every static file.
The server codes is basic like this excluding what don't makes difference:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, session
    from flask_session import Session
    from flask_cors import CORS
    
    from db import database
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'  # Substitua por uma chave segura em produção
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    Session(app)
    
    CORS(app)
    
    # Chamando a função para criar o banco de dados e as tabelas
    database.create_database()
    database.create_admin_user()
    database.create_default_keys()
    
    keys = database.get_keys()[1]
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        if 'logged_in' in session and session['logged_in']:
            credits = database.get_user_credit(session['username'])
            free_roll = database.is_free_roll(session['username'])
            session['credits'] = credits
        else:
            free_roll = False
            credits = 0
        return render_template('index.html', translate=keys['translate'], credits=credits, free_roll=free_roll)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in my html i call the statics file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/roulette_style.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/header.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/footer.css') }}">
```

follows a image of the folders structure:

[image]

and another image with the files

[image]

I'm pretty sure the code is correct cause when running in localhost no problem show up, and i more than double check if the code is similar and the folder structures aswell.
So, if someone could help I would be very grateful.

Comment: The static files seem to be called correctly. Is the folder named "static" in the same directory as app.py? Are the CSS files in the "css" directory which is a subdirectory of "static"?

Comment: yes, i really check it more than once. I updated the question adding an image of my folder structure

Comment: Have you tried removing the `static_folder='static'` parameter when instantiating your app? Does that work?

Comment: I just tried right now, and nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm using cpanel to host the application, and in cpanel you have the public_html folder, inside this folder there is a .htaccess file. It's an ocult dot file, so make sure to make it visible in settings. In my case I open up this file, edit it, letting be just the content of python from the file, I mean, there was a bunch of stuff about wordpress, and then the website works just fine.